# INPUT INTO error - Beginner MYSQL Syntax Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, terminal

I've seen other questions asking about the same thing but I can't seem to find one that solves this. I'm posting the `DESCRIBE [table];` the `INPUT INTO` and the syntax error.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE committees;
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name                 | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| num_of_members       | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created              | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| frequency_of_meeting | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| president            | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> INPUT INTO committees (name, num_of_members, created, frequency_of_meeting, president)
    -> VALUES ('Website Committee', 8, '2015-01-00', 'Every Tuesday', 'Person here')
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INPUT INTO committees (name, num_of_members, created, frequency_of_meeting, pres' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It's `INSERT INTO` not `INPUT INTO`

In the future just go to [dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)